# Flex Editable ComboBox Filters list values

Tags: apache-flex

I am working on Flex 3.6A SDK and I need to make an editable comboBox which should be able to filter the dropdown list values based on the User Inputs. I am not sure how though...plz suggest.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for an autocomplete combobox.

You can use tink's here: http://www.tink.ws/blog/filtercombobox/

code: https://code.google.com/p/tink/source/browse/trunk/flex3/src/ws/tink/mx/controls/FilterComboBox.as

swc: https://code.google.com/p/tink/downloads/detail?name=tink_flex3_mx.swc&can=2&q=

Or this one: https://github.com/Flextras/FlextrasComponents/tree/master/autoCompleteComboBox/Halo

Comment: I am though looking something like this but when I saw the code it is around 2500+ lines and not in readable format at all. 

Can you suggest something else plz.

Comment: Added the one from flextras